# Nice answer badge received for a +9/-1 answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, nice-answer

I received a [Nice Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer) badge for an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406061/26428) with 9 upvotes and 1 downvotes for a net of 8 points. Awarding this badge during the upvote revocation timeout period seems like a bug to me.

[image]

Comment: Someone wanted to donwvote you. But instead of downvoting he just clicked upvote mistakenly then he clicked downvote. And you earned the badge (9+1=10 and then 10-1-1 = 8) (I guess)

Comment: I don't believe the "possible duplicate" answer describes the scenario given in hims056's comment or juergen d' answer.

Comment: Similarly, I have just now received a nice answer badge for a +9/-0 [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3498912/26428) on another question.

Comment: It happens; sometimes you get the badge for a 10th vote that was undone.

Comment: @Dennis: That FAQ clearly explains that it's possible to reach 10, drop back under that threshold, and still receive the badge for it. We don't need separate questions and answers for every possible scenario that could award someone a badge; we need only state that it's possible to get it with a score of 9.

Comment: @animuson: I disagree. That FAQ describes *one* way, that is through a downvote, but it doesn't describe *this* way which appears to be due to a *retracted upvote*. As I described in another comment, I consider it to be a bug that badges are awarded during the timeout window for retracting upvotes.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - I can't understand your rollback. This is not a bug so [`support`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info) is an appropriate tag. And *-1 downvotes* should be *1 downvote* and *+9 upvotes* should be *9 upvotes*.

Comment: @hims056: I've removed the + and - signs. I've also tried to be more precise in my explanation of why I consider it a bug by including the information I had expressed in two comments I had previously posted.

Comment: @Dennis: So add this way to the FAQ? Like I said, **we don't need separate questions for every possible way**. That one way was only an *example*. As well, if you really think this is a bug, just saying "it seems like a bug" does not make it a bug report. You need reasons why the system shouldn't award badges within the vote revocation period. Honestly, it really doesn't matter. All that would do is decrease the *chances* of people having a badge such as this when they no longer meet the criteria. You got a badge, man, get over it.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson This is not a bug. Badges are simply awarded once the conditions are met. If these conditions then change, they are simply not revoked. If you want to keep this tagged as a bug, I'm certain this will be a [status-by-design].

Answer (score 18):

There was most probably an upvote for a short while that was removed by the voter within the 5 minute limit before the downvote was cast. Or a downvoter mistakenly upvoted your question and "corrected" that later.

However you got to the score of 10: In the meantime while you scored 10 the badge batch ran and awarded it to you. Once the badge is awarded it won't be taken from you.

Comment: Even with the mystery upvoter, the answer would have had a net score of 9 (+10/-1), no?  Unless the score was at 10, the batch ran, then the un-upvote *and* a downvote occured?

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers - See [my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177189/nice-answer-badge-received-for-a-9-1-answer#comment-532870) above

Comment: @hims056 - good call, that's what I was thinking myself

Comment: The badge won't be taken away, but if I understand correctly, the next time you earn one you won't get another (it'll "consume" this one instead).

Comment: Then it would seem to me to be a bug that a badge would be awarded before the timer expires.