# Why did I get a Nice Answer badge when the score is only 8?

Tags: support, badges, nice-answer

Is it possible that the downvoter accidentally upvoted at first, earning me the badge? (And then changed it to a downvote as intended?) I don't think badges are removed if the score drops down again? But I thought badges were only awarded after the vote was locked?

[image: achievements]

[image: answer]

[Answer link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77660/41775) for convenience.

Comment: Possibly the same scenario as in http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177189/274942.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happened in this case is that someone upvoted your answer (and made it eligible for the badge) and then switched their vote to a downvote. I'm guessing that was a misclick?

Either way, you went from 9 + 1 to a 9 - 1, but the badge had been awarded by that point and we don't retract them. FWIW, congrats?

Comment: Thanks, the badge is amazing.  :) Anyway, though, there is no time period set between the last vote and bounty going awarded?

Comment: @Fiksdal Some badges are run in batches, some are nearly instant. Depends on the performance cost of the query behind them. I don't have the code in front of me right now, but I'm gonna guess this particular badge is in the latter category. :)

Comment: @Fiksdal after a quick look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer), I'm pretty sure it's not instant, but rather run in batches every five minutes. Since the vote undo window is 5 minutes, it means the user who upvoted you took some time to undo and reverse the vote, giving the badges script time to run before doing it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard In this case, it was just crazy timing - the vote was reversed after 12 seconds.

Comment: wow, lol... so maybe the badge is instant and it only rounds to the nearest 5 minutes in the display? Otherwise it's crazy indeed!